# Customer edit tab showing blank page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am getting this error in my logs

PHP Fatal error:

> Declaration of
>   Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Attribute_Source_Website::getAllOptions()
>   must be compatible with
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table::getAllOptions($withEmpty
>   = true, $defaultValues = false) in 
>    /var/www/vhosts/goart/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Website.php
>   on line 34

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are running on PHP 7.x where method signature compatibility is strictly enforced. The only current version of Magento 1.x that supports PHP 7.x is 1.9.4.0 or patched previous versions.

If you're running a previous version and don't want to upgrade to 1.9.4.0 for some reason then the [Magento 1 PHP 7.2 patches are available here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2240)

Comment: Yes, it's due to I was using Magento 1.9.3.0. So I have updated it to 1.9.4.0. Now it's working.